# mvn clean install throwing an error - File has not been previously formatted. Please format file and commit before running validation

Tags: java, maven, formatter

After I created new files, I started getting the error "Failed to execute goal net.revelc.code.formatter:formatter-maven-plugin:2.8.1:validate File has not been previously formatted. Please format file and commit before running validation".

Any ideas why this error shows up and how to fix it?

Comment: try commit and see

Comment: did that. No luck

Comment: mvn clean validate -P format fixed the issue

Comment: Great to hear that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running

```
mvn clean validate -P format
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: This helps me to obtain an explanation of formatting errors. Thanks.

Comment: Getting following error.. could someone help me on solving this                                                                                     
     [WARNING] The requested profile "format" could not be activated because it does not exist

Answer (score 10):

The top answer indicates an issue with calling validation. If that is all set up correctly and you still run into this issue, try this.

Based on the [official usage documentation](https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/usage.html):

Run the plugin with the format goal.

```
mvn formatter:format
```

After doing this once, you should be able to run like normal.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue: *"Please format file and commit before running validation!"*

Run below command

`mvn process-sources -P format -e`

after running this command use `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean install -Pformat-code` worked for me